# Query effeciency, 3 child tables to 1 parent

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a feeling there is a better way to do this but it's not coming to mind I'm guessing I'm going to feel like an idiot after the suggestions.  The sticking point being the full outer joins in the sub query.  I have a parent table that has three child tables using the same foreign key.  If one of the child tables has data, the other two children should not have data pertaining to the same parent id.  Every row of the parent will have one row of data in one of the child tables.

Example data layout,

Parent Table:

```
TRANSACTION
ID
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Child Tables:

```
TRANSACTION_CH_A    TRANSACTION_CH_B    TRANSACTION_CH_C
T_ID_FK             T_ID_FK             T_ID_FK
1                   null                null
2                   null                null
null                3                   null
null                4                   null
null                null                5
null                null                6
```

This is the query I came up with:

```
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTION T
JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
  COALESCE (CH_A.T_ID_FK, CH_B.T_ID_FK, CH_C.T_ID_FK) AS T_ID
  FROM IPAC_OWN.TRANSACTION_CH_A CH_A
  FULL OUTER JOIN IPAC_OWN.TRANSACTION_CH_B CH_B ON CH_B.T_ID_FK = CH_A.T_ID_FK
  FULL OUTER JOIN IPAC_OWN.TRANSACTION_CH_C CH_C ON CH_C.T_ID_FK = CH_A.T_ID_FK
) 
CHILDREN ON CHILDREN.T_ID = T.ID
```

The results should contain every row in the child tables.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could so something very simple like a UNION ALL

```
SELECT T_ID_FK  FROM  TRANSACTION_CH_A WHERE T_ID_FK  IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT  T_ID_FK   FROM TRANSACTION_CH_B WHERE T_ID_FK  IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT   T_ID_FK  FROM TRANSACTION_CH_C WHERE T_ID_FK  IS NOT NULL
```

If you want nulls in you result set just take out the where clause from every select statement.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
select
    *
from
    transaction t
    join IPAC_OWN.TRANSACTION_CH_A CH_A ON CH_A.T_ID_FK = T.ID
union
select
    *
from
    transaction t
    join IPAC_OWN.TRANSACTION_CH_B CH_B ON CH_B.T_ID_FK = T.ID
union
select
    *
from
    transaction t
    join IPAC_OWN.TRANSACTION_CH_C CH_C ON CH_C.T_ID_FK = T.ID
```